# How to efficiently flip and copy a part?

Tags: modifiers, origin

I'm trying to make a tank and after I finish one of the catapillar treads, complete with all the wheels, I need to mirror it for the other side. What I'm planning to do is set the origin to the middle of the tank and use the mirror modifier to make the other copy. But I think it's an awful lot of trouble to set all the origins and give modifiers to each wheel. And if I want to animate it, I'll have to set the origins back.

Is there a better way to do this, maybe without the mirror modifier?

Comment: it's not so hard to use the mirror modifier, then make 2 separate objects and relocate the origins, but you can also make a copy of your object, then S X (or Y) -1, or ctrl M X (or Y)

Comment: You can point Mirror modifier to any object in the scene to be used as mirror plane. Select it in the Mirror Object dropdown, empty is often used for this